# Workbench timing out after 10 - 15 minutes

Tags: workbench, timeout

I'm trying to get workbench to stop timing out.  It's so irritating that it requires me to log back in ever 10-15 minutes.

This is were I set up the timeout value to be 12 hours:
Setup | Manage Apps | Connected Apps and edit Workbench to set timeouts

I tried it in an incognito window with no luck.

How do I get Workbench to stop timing out?   Many Thanks, Connie

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately,  there is no direct setting for timeout that can be used under Workbench.

However,  If you are using SOQL queries against very large data using workbench that can consume more time to execute then check the "[Asynchronous Background Processing](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/wiki#Asynchronous_Background_Processing)" framework section that allows long-running operations to be run in the background and return results when completed.

Thanks

Comment: Good to know. Thanks Vinay

Answer (score 0):

As Vinay replied, you can't control Workbench timeout duration because this is directly controlled by Workbench.

If this timeout is a blocker, you can try alternatives to Workbench:

- for running SOQL queries, try the [VS Code SQL Query Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/soql/soql-builder)
- for API calls, try the [Salesforce APIs collection](https://github.com/forcedotcom/postman-salesforce-apis) for Postman.

Comment: I'll add this to my notes.  Thanks POZ